# Run a command on CircleCI only once for a branch

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, geometry, continuous-deployment, circleci

I'm configuring my Circleci config right now to try to deploy a staging build for every new branch and then sends a message to my slack team with the link to the staging demo.

I've done the sending message to slack part, but now CircleCI sends a message to slack every time I push. I would like to limit that to happen only once for a specific branch. I know there's CIRCLE_BRANCH env that I can use to identify the current branch, but how do I save that variable in some kind of cache so I can run a conditional check on that variable to avoid running the same command twice?

I've checked the CircleCI docs and they offered cache on files but didn't mention anything about saving a variable as cache.

My config.yml file for CircleCI looks like this:

```
slackMessage:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node
    working_directory: ~/client
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/client
      # - run: echo "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" > _branch_check
      # - restore_cache:
      #     keys:
      #       - pr-{{ checksum "_branch_check" }}
      - run:
          command: |
            PR_NUMBER=${CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST##*/}
            # yolo=pr-`echo -n $CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST | md5sum`
            # if [ -f "$yolo" ]; then

            # touch $yolo
            curl -X POST <Slack API webhook curl url>
            # fi
      # - save_cache:
      #     key: pr-{{ checksum "_branch_check" }}
      #     paths:
      #       - pr-{{ checksum "_branch_check" }}
```

The lines that are commented are the saving to cache part. With these lines commented CircleCI would send a message to Slack on every push. Without the comment the expected behavior is for CircleCI to send the slack message only once for each branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Very cool question. I'll share some ideas that might work.

So, is the staging site URL created based on the branch name? Would it always be generated the same way?

If so, on CircleCI I would check for the existence of the staging URL first. If it's there, it was already created, which means this branch has already posted to Slack, and the execution can end right there.

Another idea would be to `touch .staging-created` a file into the FS, and save it into CircleCI cache using the branch name (`{{ .Branch }}`) as part of the key. Then, before sending the message to Slack, check for that file after cache has been restored.

Comment: Yes and yes, it's generated with $CIRCLE_BRANCH and $PR_NUMBER, and all the demo of the same branch would be on the same url.

Comment: I've tried the second approach and I think I was very close to nailing it but something just wasn't right in my yaml, I'll update the question with what I have right now.

Comment: What is the current issue you're having?